# Nginx specific rewrite

Tags: nginx, centos, rewrite, wordpress

i am confused in nginx rewrite.
please help me if can..Thanks you

xxxx.conf

```
#vhost-xxxxx
server {

        listen       80;
        server_name  xxxx.xxxx.com;   
        root   /var/www/html;        
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        charset utf-8;
       access_log  logs/xxxxxx.access.log;

}

#rewrite
 if (!-e $request_filename)
{

       rewrite ^(.+)$ /cn/index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {

        root           /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

}

}
```

HI all, my nginx is pointing to /var/www/html root folder
under /var/www/html i do have 3 folder cn,my,en

so for configuration up there if i proceed to xxxxx.xxxxx.com/cn/ it will be no problem.

but when i process to xxxxx.xxxxx.com/en or /my it showing 403 Forbidden.

i do try before doing these setting

```
#rewrite
 if (!-e $request_filename)
{

       rewrite ^(.+)$ /cn/index.php?q=$1 last;
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /en/index.php?q=$1 last;
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /my/index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

but only for cn it will function, other will be forbidden.

how can i make it if my user went to /en it will rewrite to

```
rewrite ^(.+)$ /en/index.php?q=$1 last;
```

or my user went to /my will rewrite to

```
rewrite ^(.+)$ /my/index.php?q=$1 last;
```

how i can make it specific

ps://my domain name is same all the way.

Thanks you, Thanks for help

Comment: You seem to have a spurious `}` before `#rewrite` but that is probably just a typo.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in my configuration file that i mention here there is no typo...btw,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three rewrite rules have an identical regex, so only the first one will ever be executed. I would suggest that you use `location` and `try_files` directives instead of `if` and `rewrite`.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log  logs/xxxxxx.access.log;

    root   /var/www/html;

    index index.php;
    location = / { return 301 /cn/; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /cn/index.php?q=$uri;
    }
    location /en {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.php?q=$uri;
    }
    location /my {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /my/index.php?q=$uri;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

*Note: I have removed and reordered some directives in your PHP location block.*

If you would like to combine the above into a regex (which is probably less efficient but extensible):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log  logs/xxxxxx.access.log;

    root   /var/www/html;

    index index.php;
    location = / { return 301 /cn/; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location ~ "^(?<lang>/\w{2})/" {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $lang/index.php?q=$uri;
    }
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) for a list of `nginx` directives and their documentation.

EDIT: Added `index` directive to both examples, `location =` to first example, and `$uri/` to each of the `try_files` in both examples. Added `try_files` to the PHP location for completeness.

Comment: Wow, work perfectly with the first example of configuration, but there another problem occur after applying this configuration, i cant access the example.com/en/wp-admin...how this can be done?

Comment: @JohnsonGoey I have updated the answer and put the index back in. See EDIT at the bottom of the answer. Please add `index.html` and `index.htm` if you also use them.

Comment: You are absolutely amazing, all the thing was done~Thanks you so much...Thanks a lot.